# Когда может быть полезна команда rake db:schema:load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В Rails есть команда rake `db:schema:load`. Когда она может быть полезна, в каких случаях ее применять?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Команда полезна, если вам нужно одним махом выставить структуру в базе данных такую же, как в `schema.rb` или `schema.sql` вашего проекта.

Обычно структура БД модифицируется через миграции и `rake db:migrate`. Такой способ хорош по трем причинам:

1. **Инкрементальное изменение БД** - накатываются только те миграции, которые еще не накатывались на текущую БД;
2. **Нет угрозы потери существующих данных** - в уже существующие таблицы и данные в них не вносятся изменения, если только это явно не указано в новых миграциях;
3. **Возможность отката на n миграций назад** - с помощью `rake db:rollback`.

При этом также обновляется файл `schema.rb`. После последовательной накатки всех миграций, в этом файле будет структура, отражающая все изменения через миграции, от самой первой до самой последней из накатанных. И, по-хорошему, этот файл нужно коммитить в git наряду с другими файлами проекта.

---

Теперь представим ситуацию:

- В проекте заведены несколько веток, на несколько разных фич;
- В каждой ветке, так или иначе, оказалось нужно модифицировать структуру БД;
- Значит в каждой ветке есть какие-то свои миграции;
- Мы находимся в ветке A, создали в ней миграции, накатили их - изменили структуру БД;
- Внезапно нам понадобилось перейти на ветку Б и что-то сделать там;
- Мы перескакиваем на нее с помощью `git checkout Б`;
- Теперь в редакторе мы видим код ветки Б, и можем с ним работать;
- **Но в БД осталась структура данных, созданная за счет миграций из ветки А.**

Вот такой конфликт. В идеале нам нужно убрать из БД все таблицы, поля и индексы, созданные миграциями из ветки А, перейти на ветку Б, и накатить все миграции из ветки Б. Примерно так:

- `rake db:rollback` - n-раз, чтобы откатить n-миграций;
- `git checkout Б`;
- `rake db:migrate`.

А когда мы все сделаем в ветке Б и захотим вернуться в ветку А - нам понадобиться снова проделать эту последовательность операций. Откатить все миграции ветки Б, перейти на ветку А, и накатить все миграции ветки А.

`rake db:schema:load` помогает избавиться от этого. Дело в том, что в каждой ветке, когда мы создавали миграции, накатывали их и делали коммит - мы коммитили также и файл `schema.rb`. Значит, если мы с ветки А перейдем в ветку Б - мы увидим, что структура в `schema.rb` соответствует ровно тем миграциям, которые должны применяться в ветке Б. И мы можем эту структуру просто загрузить в БД. В итоге - алгоритм перехода с ветки на ветку упрощается до:

- `git checkout Любая-ветка`
- `rake db:schema:load`

Но остается нюанс. Так как `db:schema:load`, по сути, накатывает готовую структуру на базу данных с нуля - все существующие таблицы, и, что важно нам, данные в таблицах - удаляются. То есть на выходе мы получаем, пусть и БД с актуальной структурой, но без данных. И накатывание этих данные нам нужно продумывать отдельно. Один из вариантов - хранить накатку данных в `seeds.rb` и после перехода на другую ветку и применения `rake db:schema:load` применять также `rake db:seed`.

Answer (score 1):

Она может быть полезна в том случае, если вам требуется воссоздать структуру базы данных в другом окружении/базе, не задействуя миграции (допустим по той причине, что они выполняются слишком долго). Например, для тестового окружения вы можете выполнить команду

```
rake db:test:load
```

и в тестовой базе данных будет развернута текущая схема из db/schema.rb, без последовательного выполнения миграций. Это становится особенно важно в том случае, когда вы работаете в контейнерах и прогоны тестов у вас начинаются каждый раз с чистой базы данных, а схлапывать старые миграции (заменяя их содержимым schema.rb) вы в силу каких-то причин не хотите (например, у вас там хранятся комментарии по причинам выбора индекса).